# Load foreach table in a modal which is called from another foreach table

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

i have a modal with a table in in. i load the modal from a foreach table. i believe my code is right but i dont know why it displays in a funny way. this is my code and when i run this code this is the result i get. click on the link to view the image [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RwSK.png)

```
 <tbody>
           <?php
                        $count = 1; 
                        $notarray = DataDB::getInstance()->select_from_where('order_collective','user_id',$userid);
                        foreach($notarray as $row):
                        $address = $row['appartment'].",".$row['address'].",".$row['city'].",".$row['state'].".".$row['landmark'];
                        ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $count++;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['trackingnumber'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo "NGN ".number_format($row['price'], 2);?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $address;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['order_date'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo DataDB::getInstance()->get_name_from_id('name','delivery_status','delivery_status_id',$row['delivery_status']);?></td>

              <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myVie<?php echo $row['trackingnumber'] ?>">View</button>

                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
             <?php include ('order_history_modal.php'); ?>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            </tbody>
 <!-- ORDER HISTORY Modal content-->
  <div id="myVie<?php echo $row['trackingnumber'] ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

           <div class="table-responsive">
                      <table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
        $notal = DataDB::getInstance()->select_from_where('order_details','trackingnumber',$row['trackingnumber']);             
        foreach($notal as $rol):
        $prrname = DataDB::getInstance()->get_name_from_id('product_name','product','product_id',$rol['product_id']);?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $prrname ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rol['quantity'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo "NGN ".number_format($rol['price'], 2);?></td>
  </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
 </table>
                        <p></p>
                      </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you get  $row['order_collective_id'] out side the loop? for every row you should write your code inside the loop so its work for all rows.

Comment: presently the modal is included inside of the loop@ZaidBinKhalid

Comment: Show your complete peace of code. If you call model by ID then ID should be unique. And it batter to write your model inside the loop with unique row ID. Try with pasting code inside the loop instead of including file.

Comment: its already unique and its inside the foreach loop, that is the code above, from what is there, am including the modal in the foreach loop and am attaching <?php echo $row['trackingnumber'] ?> to myVie to make it unique, done modal pop us a lot, if i remove the for each table in the modal, the modal works well and the unique id will still be functioning for me to get order details with it. the problem is it is showing that result whenever i put it in a table

Comment: Make it simple first. Write your code inside the loop without including file. And then try it will work.

Comment: the modal works well but once i say <table></table> even if the table tag is empty. it shows that behaviour @ZaidBinKhalid

Comment: Then the format of your HTML structure is not valid.

Comment: thats why am here, to know what am doing wrong @ZaidBinKhalid

Comment: use **nested table** Your current code is not in a nested table format. where you add model page, you are not using tr or td and then you close your table in a model which is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Track Number</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Order Date</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Auction</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody>
    <?php
        $count = 1; 
        $notarray = DataDB::getInstance()->select_from_where('order_collective','user_id',$userid);
        foreach($notarray as $row):
        $address = $row['appartment'].",".$row['address'].",".$row['city'].",".$row['state'].".".$row['landmark'];
        ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $count++;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['trackingnumber'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo "NGN ".number_format($row['price'], 2);?></td>
        <td><?php echo $address;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['order_date'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo DataDB::getInstance()->get_name_from_id('name','delivery_status','delivery_status_id',$row['delivery_status']);?></td>
        <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myVie<?php echo $row['trackingnumber'] ?>">View</button>
        </div>
        <?php include ('order_history_modal.php'); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>  
    <?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**order_history_modal.php**

```
<div id="myVie<?php echo $row['trackingnumber'] ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                <?php 
                $notal = DataDB::getInstance()->select_from_where('order_details','trackingnumber',$row['trackingnumber']);             
                foreach($notal as $rol):
                    $prrname = DataDB::getInstance()->get_name_from_id('product_name','product','product_id',$rol['product_id']);?>
                    <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $prrname ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $rol['quantity'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "NGN ".number_format($rol['price'], 2);?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
                </table>
             </div> 
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="table">
 <thead>
     <tr>
         <th>#</th>
            <th>Track Number</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Order Date</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Auction</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
         <td>1</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myVie1">View</button>
            </div>
         <div id="myVie1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
              <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th>Item</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td>test</td>
                                <td>test</td>
                                <td>test</td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </div> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
   </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The code snippet editor has a `tidy` option, would improve your answer if you used it.