# how to open multiple modal click on id?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli, bootstrap-modal

code:

```
<style>
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<script>
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
  btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
  }
  span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
</script>



 <?php      
  $sql = "select * from enquires2";
  $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
  {
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span><img src='gridview/view.png' alt='View' id='myBtn<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <div id='myModal' class='modal'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <span class='close'>&times;</span>
      <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
  }
?>
```

In this code when I click on id i.e.

```
id='myBtn<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'
```

it display only one modal but when I click on new row id it show nothing. so, I want to open multiple modal with different row id. How can I fix this issue ? please help.

Thank You

Comment: have you tried printing id when you click on new row?

Comment: You need to see this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843806/load-foreach-table-in-a-modal-which-is-called-from-another-foreach-table/43864617#43864617

Comment: If I understand, you want to open multiple modals with a button click?